# Getting data from txt file to php's array

Tags: php, arrays

I have some data in txt file that looks like:

```
data1
data2
....
```

I want it to export it into an array so I'm trying to make it with PHP:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
$members = array();

while (!feof($file)) {
   $members[] = fgets($file);
}

fclose($file);

var_dump($members);
?>
```

However it generates associative array like `[0]=> string(5) "data1" [1]=> string(5) "data2"` and I need it to work in javascript, so how can I easily export it to look like `["data1","data2",...]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the word `array` in a double sense: What you see from `print_r()` is an **array in PHP representation**, what you want to get is an **array in JSON representation**. Both of them descrive essentially the same data structure.

The way to convert this, is to use `json_encode()`:

```
echo json_encode($members);
```

will do the trick.